# SAML Provision Error

Tags: saml

We are trying to initiate Salesforce from company's portal and it was working fine until yesterday.

We are getting "SAML Provision Error" while trying to launch Salesforce via SSO from Portal.

On SAML Assertion Validation we found the below results :

```
Last recorded SAML login failure: 2012-10-10T16:02:40.294Z
Unexpected Exceptions
Ok
1. Validating the Status
Ok
2. Looking for an Authentication Statement
Ok
3. Looking for a Conditions statement
Ok
4. Checking that the timestamps in the assertion are valid
Timestamp of the response is outside of allowed time window
Current time is: 2012-10-10T16:19:25.512Z
Timestamp is: 2012-10-10T16:02:38.000Z
Allowed skew in milliseconds is 480000
Timestamp of the assertion is outside of allowed time window
Current time is: 2012-10-10T16:19:25.512Z
Timestamp is: 2012-10-10T16:02:38.000Z
Allowed skew in milliseconds is 480000
5. Checking that the Attribute namespace matches, if provided
Not Provided
6. Miscellaneous format confirmations
Ok
7. Confirming Issuer matches
Ok
8. Confirming a Subject Confirmation was provided and contains valid timestamps
Ok
9. Checking that the Audience matches, if provided
Ok
10. Checking the Recipient
Organization Id that we expected: 00DJ0000000795H
Organization Id that we found based on your assertion: 00DJ0000000795H
11. Validating the Signature
Is the response signed? true
Is the assertion signed? false
Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? true
Ok
12. Checking that the Site URL Attribute contains a valid site url, if provided
Not Provided
13. Looking for portal and organization id, if provided
Not Provided
```

Please advise what is the issue here.

Comment: Vimal - I assume you go this working by correcting the time on your server. If so, please 'accept' Jon's answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure on this and am assuming you control the company portal server. It seems that its internal clock is more than 8 mins (480000 milliseconds) out of sync with that of the Salesforce server.

Try updating / setting the clock on the company portal server so its within 8 mins of the Salesforce servers timestamp.